# Losing connections from GCE to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

For the past 3 days I have been executing long SQL queries without any problems, including this morning when I ran queries longer than 1200 seconds.

But now I am getting:

```
> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

sample execution is:

```
marcelo@node:~$ sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 60 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5 
marcelo@node:~$ mysql -uroot -p -DmyDb -hmyIP < receivedcytext.txt >out.txt 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The error is given at random periods. Between 5 and 15 minutes into execution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be the issue given when your errors are being generated. Nevertheless, this ['Lost connection to MySQL server'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html) article shows how this error may be encountered when writing a significant number or rows.

The article suggests setting the [`net_read_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout) to something greater than the default value of 30 seconds. Also, if your queries take quite long to run, you may want to consider breaking them up into smaller units.

Comment: It was not an issue with code or settings. I was instructed to email google support with details of my instance and it was solved shortly afterwards.